Extract Data From Bar Graph With Easyocr
I have a problem reading the data in the dataset I have and it always ends up reading one letter/word out of order. I am trying to extract the column names from the bar graph images I added in the subject. I tried pytesseract before, but I switched to easyocr because I was not satisfied with the output.
I have tried resolution, anti-aliasing (Median, Gaussian), etc. methods, but while I correct the data read in one image, I distort it in the other.To fix the broken word, I tried to send the broken word to the language libraries (BERT, nltk) and get the word I was looking for, but I couldn't get the correct result.
What works for me is to rotate the names in the vertical bar graphs 90 degrees for proper reading. My other method is to crop a certain part of the image so that I don't get the data from the rest of the image, except for the words I want. Apart from these, can anyone help me how to read the dataset properly with a high accuracy rate?
def find_barNames_OCR(image, bar):
    # EasyOCR modelini yüklew
    reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'], model_storage_directory='easyocr_models')

    if(bar == 1):
        rotation_matrix = image
    else:
        rotation_matrix = cv2.rotate(image, cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE)

    str_gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(rotation_matrix, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    str_rez_image = cv2.resize(str_gray_image, (800, 600))

    height, width = str_gray_image.shape[:2]
    print(f"Resolution: {height} x {width}")

    clippedImage = str_gray_image[:, int(width // 1.6):]

    results = reader.readtext(clippedImage, detail=3)
    cv2.imshow("Final picture", clippedImage)

    word_list = []
    for (bbox, text, prob) in results:
        if(len(text) >= 3):
            word_list.append(text)
        print(f"Metin: {text}   Olasılık: {prob}")

    return word_list

Link to the dataset I use: URL
Vertical:



Horizontal:



